# Can not understand the idea/usefulness of edit distance among strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, levenshtein-distance

I am reading about the problem of Edit Distance between 2 strings.
It can be solved by Dynamic Programming using a formula of Edit Distance. What I can not understand is its usefulness. 
First of all how is this any different than knowing the longest common subsequense of 2 strings?
If the idea is to pick a string with the smallest edit distance you might as well use the max LCS among the strings.Right?
Additionally when we actually code to do the replacement, the code would be similar to the following:

```
if(a.length == b.length){  
   for(int i = 0;i < a.length;i++){  
          a[i] = b[i];  
   }  
}  
else{   
    a = new char[b.length];  
    for(int i = 0;i < a.length;i++){  
          a[i] = b[i];  
    }    
}
```

I mean just replace the characters. Is there any difference between doing an assignment and checking if the characters are the same and if not, only then do the assignment at runtime? Aren't both constant time operations?
What am I misunderstanding with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Edit Distance and LCS are related by a simple formula if no substitution is allowed in editing (or if substitution is twice as expensive as insertion or deletion):

ed(x,y) = x.length + y.length - 2*lcs(x,y).length

If substitution is a separate unit-cost operation, then ED can be less than that. This is important in practice since we want a way to create shorter diff files. Not just asymptotically bounded up to a constant factor, but actually smallest possible ones.

**Edit** shorter diff files are probably not a concern here, they won't be substantially shorter if we do not allow substitution. There are more interesting applications, like ranking correction suggestions in a spell checker (this is based on a comment by @nhahtdh below).

Comment: My original assumption is that an assignment is constant time in OP.Is this is what you mean by substitution?

Comment: "Edit Distance" depends on the cost function. There are a lot of cost functions used for different for different problems.

Comment: @MrSmith42:I don't know what you mean by "cost function"

Comment: @Cratylus: You can assign different cost for delete/insert/change. For example, if you know that people is more likely to mistype character rather than typing less or more character, then you can give less cost to change, and more cost to insert or delete. This cost will allow you to rank the word correction suggestions.

Comment: @Cratylus: each edit-operation has a cost value. The allowed edit operations can be very different and the costs can be defined very different. E.g. the levinstein distance has the cost of 1 for insert, delet and replacement of one character.

Comment: @Cratylus: there can also be more or less edit operations than insert, delete, replace one character. E.g. swap adjacent characters is also used in some use cases. Or cost of insert or delete may decrease for longer sequences inserted / deleted.

Comment: @MrSmith42:`each edit-operation has a cost value`.Is this different than the runtime cost?It seems you and @nhahtdh imply something different than the runtime cost

Comment: @Cratylus: *runtime cost* means the time complexity of the algorithm. The *cost function* is used to define how 'bad' an edit operation is. Most simple cost functions can be calculated in **O(1)** time.

Comment: @MrSmith42:But is an edit operation something else than a variable assignment?

Comment: @Cratylus: For each step in the dynamic programming you need to calculate the costs for all the edit-operations and than calculate the minimum. As an example see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Definition

Answer (score 0):

Edit distance is quite different form LCS. 
The *edit distance* is the minimal number of edit operations you need to transform the one String to the other String. A very popular example is the  [Levinstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which has the edit operations:

- insert one character
- delete one character
- replace one character

All this operations a biased with a cost of *1*.

Put there are a lot of other operations and cost functions possible.
E.g. you could also allow the operation: swap two adjacent characters.

It is e.g. used to align DNA-sequences (or protein-sequences).

If the STring have length n and m the complexity is:
time: **O(n*m)**
space: **O(min(n,m))**

Can became worse for complex cost-functions.

Comment: If you have 2 strings e.g. `network` and `rooter` then the LCS is 2.This means that if you want to go from `rooter` to `network` then 2 characters will be unmodified while the rest `size(rooter) - 2 + (abs(size(network) - size(rooter))` will change. So the strings with the smallest edit distance are those with the max LCS

Comment: @Cratylus: Maybe I am blind ATM, but which LCS of `network` and `rooter` has the length 2?

Comment: `tr` is the LCS of `network` and `rooter`.LCS does not need to be contiguous

Comment: @MrSmith42:Actually the LCS of `aaaaa` and `ababa` is 3

Comment: @Cratylus: I should have read better. You clearly said you were talking about longest common subsequence. I had longest commen substring in mind. n.m.'s answer shows the relation of the two problems you are talking about.